# Generate x.509 key pair on Linux for use with Windows

Tags: linux, powershell, x509, windows-server, key-pair

I've built a LAMP solution that generates many powershell files that are automated to run on many Windows Servers.

I need to generate a public/private key pair within Linux, so that I can sign the powershell files and then verify their authenticity in Windows, via powershell's execution policy being set to "AllSigned"

I've tried PGP but have found that the public key it generates is not accepted by Windows Server's certificate manager.

I'd like to use private keys that are not backed by a Root Authority, and there are many different powershell scripts that need to be authenticated and run on many Windows servers.

My question is - How to generate x.509 keypair that windows certificate manager will accept, that will work with Powershell's "AllSigned" execution policy?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using openssl command?

See http://www.ipsec-howto.org/x595.html

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for! OpenSSL ! I was able to create a public/private key pair and import the public key into my test Windows Server! Although I made many references from this web page: https://raymii.org/s/tutorials/Sign_and_verify_text_files_to_public_keys_via_the_OpenSSL_Command_Line.html

Answer (score 2):

As @Peter suggested, OpenSSL was the answer!

Following instructions on this page, I was able to generate my own public/private key pair and import the public key into Windows Server Certificate Manager.

I used this command to generate the keys:

```
openssl req -nodes -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout "PrivateKey.key" -out "PublicKey.crt" -days 99999
```